# Policy in Linux file descriptor multiplexing (select et al.)

Tags: linux, events, select, epoll

I was wondering whether there is - at least under Linux - a system call that watches a set of file descriptors and first "serves" the first file descriptor that got ready for operation.

I have been working with `select` and I do not expect that `select` enforces a kind of FirstComeFirstServed policy on the descriptors that watches, because its implementation should be a slight variation on polling.

Maybe I am asking for an event-driven handler, but I do not know anything about `epoll` beyond its mere existence.

Thanks

Comment: why do you need this FCFS behaviour?

Comment: Packet sniffing on several interfaces.

Comment: `select(2)` et alia already reveal which FDs require attention. How is this different from what you need?

Comment: I am searching for proof/documentation that `select` always serves in temporal order the FDs that require attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All event demultiplexers (`select`/`poll`/`epoll`) signal all the FDs which need attention at that moment (based on the watch sets you provided), there's no difference, except that `epoll` can also be used in an edge-triggered way.

At any moment the result set can contain multiple FDs (without any additional ordering) as you're running on a multitasking OS, so by the time your process gets scheduled multiple events could have happened.  Note: running an RT (Real-Time) kernel with your process set to high or realtime priority might help...

Comment: When I have several FDs ready, the "servicing" order is then dependent on the FDs' order in the watch set. Am I right ?

Comment: There is no order in the watch set. It's a **set**, in the mathematical sense of the word. In the result there is **no** order either... you decide which FDs to serve first.

Comment: Thus I assume there is no enforcing of FCFS when multiple descriptors happen to be ready (because of scheduling and etc).